# Distributing android vertical SeekBars evenly across parent

Tags: android, seekbar

I have created a "standard" vertical SeekBar with the code below (posted numerous times here on SO).

```
package com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar{

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }   

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }   

}
```

Now I want to use 6 of these in my view. If I just use RelativeLayout to place them next to each other everything is fine (can't post images, lack the reputation...).

However I want them distributed evenly across the view horizontally and if I in the layout XML add them as children of LinearLayout and set a weight of 1 for each, the progressDrawable (I think it is - the "bar") will fill the entire view width with just a little padding and the thumb will be placed in the left side.

Now I understand why this happens but I don't know how to work around it. I.e. how can I keep the default proportions and still distribute the SeekBars evenly across the view centering the progressDrawable and thumb in each view?

I'm new to android and Java development in general, so bear with me. I hope I managed to explain the problem.

The XML layout that gives me the chubby SeekBars is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/cream"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".EditInst"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#ffffbc40"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/instTxt"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>         

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/SeekBars"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">  

        <com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq.VerticalSeekBar android:id="@+id/f0SeekBar" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq.VerticalSeekBar android:id="@+id/f1SeekBar" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq.VerticalSeekBar android:id="@+id/f2SeekBar" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq.VerticalSeekBar android:id="@+id/cSeekBar" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq.VerticalSeekBar android:id="@+id/sSeekBar" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <com.plainfieldworks.nofiseq.VerticalSeekBar android:id="@+id/dSeekBar" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is probably to simply add another layer in between. You can use something like a `FrameLayout` where your current SeekBars are, so that you have "chubby `FrameLayout`s" and then in each of these `FrameLayout`s put a SeekBar.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That and "android:layout_gravity="center"" on each SeekBar did the trick.